# Plot 2-D system difference equations

Tags: plotting, difference-equations

If I have 2-D system difference equations
                             x(n+1)=x(n)-5y(n)  ,
                              y(n+1)= 2x(n)+y(n)
I need to plot this system. I did :

```
StreamPlot[{x - 5 y , 2 x + y} == {x, y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

Is this code correct ? Thank you so much

[image]

Comment: What about just solving that system with `RSolve`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is quite correct.  To test my hypothesis, I created this:

```
NextXY[{x_, y_}] := {x - 5 y, 2 x + y}
```

Then, I created some points:

```
somePoints = {#, NextXY[#]} & /@ 
   Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, -1, 1, .2}, {y, -1, 1, .2}], 1];
```

And plotted them with arrows:

```
Graphics[Arrow[#] & /@ somePoints]
```

[image]
This looks a whole lot more like this stream plot:

```
StreamPlot[{x - 5 y, 2 x + y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, seems like my (now deleted) comment wasn't right. But this doesn't exactly match up a trajectory either.  Try `pts = NestList[NextXY, {0.002, 0}, 5]; ListLinePlot[pts, PlotRange -> All]`.  Maybe a `StreamPlot` just isn't a good idea for a discrete-time system.

Comment: Hi guys, solving by hands, i got the eigenvalues are complex. {1 + I Sqrt[10], 1 - I Sqrt[10]}. so it looks spiral unstable?